# SQL Server query duplicating rows based on inventory locations that have been claused out

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, join

My current code is duplicating results per `item_id`. I am summing the previous three months usage per item in two locations. I do have more locations but I limited it in the WHERE clause. I think the query is showing the extra results due to the other locations. Can someone help me clean up my code?

The usage column is YYYYMM format

```
select distinct
    u.location, u.item_id, l.qty_on_hand, u.inv_min, u.usage
from
    inv_usage as u
left join 
    inventory_location as l on u.inv_id = u.inv_id and l.location = u.location
where 
    u.year_period >= cast(convert(char(6), dateadd(month, -3, cast(convert(char(6), getdate(), 112) + '01' as date)), 112) as int)
    and l.location in ('1', '2')
    and u.location in ('1', '2')
```

Table for Inventory Quantity on Hand:

```
l.location   l.inv_id   l.qty_on_hand   l.inv_min
--------------------------------------------------
1            1           100             100
2            1            10              10
1            2           200             200
2            2            20              20
1            3           300             300
2            3            30              30
```

Table for Inventory Usage:

```
u.location   u.inv_id   u.item_id   u.inv_min   u.year_period   u.usage
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1            1           item1       100         202002          100
2            1           item1        10         202002           10
1            1           item1       100         202002          100
2            1           item1        10         202002           10
1            1           item1       100         202002          100
2            1           item1        10         202002           10
1            2           item2       200         202003          200
2            2           item2        20          202003          20
1            2           item2       200         202003          200
2            2           item2        20         202003           20
1            2           item2       200         202003          200
2            2           item2        20         202003           20
1            3           item3       300         202004          300
2            3           item3        30         202004           30
1            3           item3       300         202004          300
2            3           item3        30         202004           30
1            3           item3       300         202004          300
2            3           item3        30         202004           30
```

My desired result sums the usage for the previous three months per location and show the current quantity in inventory.

```
?.location    u.item_id    l.qty_on_hand   ?.inv_min   u.usage  
--------------------------------------------------------------
1             1            100             100         300
2             1             10              10          30
1             2            200             200         600
2             2             20              20          60
1             3            300             300         900
2             3             30              30          90
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Including DDL keeps us form guessing the data types of the columns, e.g. `location` appears to be both an integer and a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    il.*,
    (
        select sum(iu.usage)
        from inventory_usage iu
        where 
            iu.location = il.location
            and iu.inv_id = il.inv_id
            and iu.year_period >= 
                year(dateadd(month, -3, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))) * 100
                + month(dateadd(month, -3, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)))
            and iu.year_period < 
                year(datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)) * 100
                + month(datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
    ) usage
from inventory_location il
```

The conditions on the date may look lengthy, however they look to me like the most efficient way to filter; they make the query SARGeable, and would take advantage of an index on `inventory_usage(location, inv_id, year_period)`.